# Error installing paypal-ios-sdk

Tags: paypal, swift3

When i am integrating pod file. I didn't get any error message before using cocoapods, now i am integrating cocoapods using Paypal-iOS-SDk. I got an error: If anyone know how to solve this error please tell me. My email id: kosuruudaysaikumar@gmail.com

```
Last login: Fri Jun  9 11:37:40 on ttys001
shyams-Mac-mini:~ shyamnarla$ cd /Users/shyamnarla/Downloads/Amaravati\  
shyams-Mac-mini:Amaravati  shyamnarla$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (4.0.1)
Using AlamofireImage (3.1.0)
Installing CardIO (5.4.1)
Using Firebase (3.9.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.5.1)
Using FirebaseCore (3.4.4)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
Using FirebaseMessaging (1.2.1)
Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2)
Using GoogleMaps (2.1.0)
Using GooglePlacePicker (2.1.0)
Using GooglePlaces (2.1.0)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.0)
Installing PayPal-iOS-SDK (2.17.0)

[!] Error installing PayPal-iOS-SDK
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK.git /var/folders/b3/8tmw3ywx53vb9h7qvzgrpr2r0000gn/T/d20170609-2132-1pgwyuv --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 2.17.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/b3/8tmw3ywx53vb9h7qvzgrpr2r0000gn/T/d20170609-2132-1pgwyuv'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -36
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed


[!] Smart quotes were detected and ignored in your Podfile. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.

[!] Automatically assigning platform ios with version 10.0 on target Amaravati because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```